# How to set the size and the position of a dialog button libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, dialog

I want to have a pop up window in my app. Therefore I wrote the following code:

```
public void show() {    
skin4 = new Skin (Gdx.files.internal("NoAdsButton.json"));
button4 = new Button(skin4);
button4.setPosition(25,1250);
button4.setSize(120,120);
            button4.addListener(new ClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                    skin5 = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("Test.json"));
                    dialog = new Dialog("", skin5);
                    dialog.setTransform(true);
                    dialog.button("REMOVE ADS:   1.99$");
                    dialog.button("UNLOCK ALL MODES:     1.99$");
                    dialog.setSize(700,500);
                    dialog.setPosition(50,400);
                    stage.addActor(dialog);
                }
            });

            stage.addActor(button4);
}
```

Unfortunately, `dialog.setSize()` only stretches the dialog but not the buttons. I also don´t know how to set the position of the two buttons and how to change the size of the text which is in the buttons. **Could somebody help me to reach that?**

Answer (score -1):

Create a custom dialog

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
    textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv); //dialog component
    dialog.setTitle("Title"); //set Title
```

after then u can use the component just like normal component. don't forget to dismiss the dialog when it need to be dismissed.

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: Is that for libGDX?

Comment: for creating a dialog with your own layout

Comment: This answer is specifically for Android, and will not work in LibGDX.